# Regex: Match unbalanced and balanced strings in two capture groups

Tags: regex, perl

I am pretty decent with `regex` matching, but this below has me stumped this Friday afternoon. I have the below 3 variants of a string in a "date" format that I need to send to `MySQL` as a range to get the matching results in between. As a background the data comes from a `JSON` source I have no control over, and is processed by `Perl` before being passed to `MySQL`. Everything works great except for the last variant.

**Variants to Match**

```
2014-04-01~2014-04-16
~2014-04-16
2014-04-01~
```

The first one is a range. The second one is from the beginning of time to the date, and the last one is from the date to the end of time.

**Current Regex**

```
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})~|~(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/g;
```

**[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vD0kT5)**

Now I have been through a ton of `Regex` combinations and the one listed is merely the last one I was working with.

The issue is that I need to specify the dates as `from` and `to`. This is fine when I have both dates as I have two capture groups, and okay with only the start time as it is automatically the first capture group, but where I am having difficulties is when only the "from the beginning of time to the date" is used as it is placed in the first capture group and as shown below I would LIKE it to be in the second capture group.

**Example Usage in Perl**

```
my $date = '~2014-04-01';

my ($f,$t) = $date =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/gm;
print "FROM: " . $f . "\n";
print "TO: " . $t . "\n";
```

I don't want to use multiple `regex` patterns in the `perl` and would like to limit the `perl` to only the above with the `regex` doing the heavy lifting.

Can anyone provide a solution for the `regex` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?~(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?/) {
        if (defined $1 && defined $2) {
            print "a range <$1> to <$2>\n";

        } elsif (defined $1) {
            print "a start <$1>\n";

        } elsif (defined $2) {
            print "a stop <$2>\n";

        } else {
            print "just a ~, ignore\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
2014-04-01~2014-04-16
~2014-04-16
2014-04-01~
```

Outputs:

```
a range <2014-04-01> to <2014-04-16>
a stop <2014-04-16>
a start <2014-04-01>
```

Comment: aarrgghh I wasted to much time on this making it way to complicated. Completely forgot the `?` Optional meta-character existed from some reason. @Miller thanks it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Note that I defined `$date` to hold the repeated portion of the regex. I think this helps a bit with readability.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = q(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2});
my ($from, $to);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    if (/^($date)~($date)$|^(~)($date)$|^($date)(~)$/) {
    #     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^
    #           (1)             (2)          (3)

        ($from, $to) = ($1, $2) if defined($1);  # pattern (1)
        ($from, $to) = ($3, $4) if defined($3);  # pattern (2)
        ($from, $to) = ($5, $6) if defined($5);  # pattern (3)

        print $_, " => [$from][$to]\n";
    }
}

__END__
2014-04-01~2014-04-16
~2014-04-16
2014-04-01~
```

**Expected Output**

```
2014-04-01~2014-04-16 => [2014-04-01][2014-04-16]
~2014-04-16 => [~][2014-04-16]
2014-04-01~ => [2014-04-01][~]
```

Comment: This solution does work, but I chose the accepted answer as it used a minimal amount of capture groups (the minimum), and allowed the `regex` to work with the existing `perl` code `my ($f,$t) = $date =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/gm;`. Thank you for the submission.